Nvim arrow cannot show statusline in lualine
I try to use
 local statusline = require('arrow.statusline')
statusline.is_on_arrow_file()
statusline.text_for_statusline()
statusline.text_for_statusline_with_icons()

With lualine to display statusline in a segment. But nothing is showen on the lualine even if the file is bookmarked.
